# Save to SQL DataBase

Tags: admin, database, magento-1, login

I have an observer that listens for when a customer is successfully registered! Using the Magento Event: **customer_register_success**

I have a custom table called "am_perm" I'm able to manually go into my database and write the SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `am_perm`(`uid`, `cid`) VALUES (25, 139)
```

and it works perfectly!  However in my event observer it does not work!

Here is my code in the event listener the params passed in are:

**$userId = 25 & $customerId = 139**

```
public function assignDealer(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    function assignOneCustomer($userId, $customerId)
    {
        try {
            $userId = intVal($userId);
            $customerId = intVal($customerId);

            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
            $themeTable = $resource->getTableName('am_perm');
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `am_perm`(`uid`, `cid`) VALUES ($userId, $customerId)";
            $writeConnection->query($sql);//insert
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            die($e);
        }
    }


    $registerParams = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    $paramMerchantCode = $registerParams['merchant_code'];

    if (isset($paramMerchantCode)) {

        $customerId = $observer->getCustomer()->getId();
        $merchantIdArray = array();

        //Grab the Admin_Role Table from SQL
        $model = Mage::getModel('admin/role');
        //Grab all roles with Merchant but only need the first one for ID
        //Table will be massive unless we use relational database ID versus primary ID
        $role = $model->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('role_name', ['eq' => "Merchant"])->getFirstItem();

        //Loop through database and grab all ID's for Merchants and place into $mcArray
        if ($roleId = $role->getId()) {
            $dealerArray = $model->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', ['eq' => $roleId]);
            foreach ($dealerArray as $currentDealer) {
                array_push($merchantIdArray, $currentDealer['user_id']);
            }
        }

        //Look up Merchants and compare code to Merchant Code
        //If Code matches we store the $merchantId
        foreach ($merchantIdArray as $id) {
            $adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id);
            $userMerchantCode = $adminUser->getData("merchant_code");
            if (strtolower($paramMerchantCode) == strtolower($userMerchantCode)) {
                $uid = $id;
            }
        }
        if ($uid && $customerId) {
            Mage::getModel('amperm/perm')->assignOneCustomer($uid, $customerId);
        }
    }


}
```

It never catches the Exception $e but it also never saves to my database?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown in file Mage_Customer_AccountController . As this error is coming when you are creating a new customer so this error must be thrown in createPostAction.go to catch block in this action and you will see that cannot save customer data message is being set in session on line no 319 .
So in that block you may print $e->getMessage() like this

```
print_r($e->getMessage());
die(get_class($this));//this will help you to find the class where you have written die , if in case you forget the file where you have placed die;
```

make sure you take a backup of this file before making any changes in it.
you will see the error message which may be helpfull to solve the error message.

Comment: Did you mean line 419? I receive the following message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/makeyou/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 423"

Comment: the magento i checked had this on line 319.
file path is app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

Comment: also if i copy what you typed I receive: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/makeyou/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 422"

Comment: What is the exact file path?

Comment: i edited my answer. by mistaked i missed last ) in second line of my code.
exact file path is app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.ph‌​p

Comment: I'm in the AccountController.php, are you referring to put my code inside the function _successProcessRegistration?

Comment: no am referring you to put the code inside public function createPostAction() . Just scroll down in the same action and you will see two catch blocks. add the code that i have commented in last catch block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54042/discussion-between-simplysaif-and-codingmagesheen).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
function assignOneCustomer($userId, $customerId)
        {
            try
            {
                $userId = intVal($userId);
                $customerId = intVal($customerId);

                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
                $themeTable = 'am_perm';
                $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $themeTable ."(uid, cid) VALUES (".$userId.",". $customerId.")";//insert only
                $writeConnection->query($sql);//insert
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I take out                 $writeConnection->update($sql);//insert it has no error and creates the customer normally however they have no "dealer" which is what this observer is trying to do it's attempting to link the uid(userId) with the cid(customerId)

Comment: Please let me know what you want to do i can't getting whats your exact approch

Comment: I want to create in the table am_perm a row thats fills in for uid and cid then saves it

Comment: Right now if I don't have the line:  $writeConnection->update($sql); It doesn't save it to the table but it also doesn't throw an error

Comment: Update code please check it

Comment: dang still doesn't work but holy moley I thought you got it. I know it's something really small like a syntax error.  It's not even getting to the catch(Exception $e) line but its also not saving to the database

Comment: what's really weird is I can manually update this table using INSERT INTO `am_perm`(`uid`, `cid`) VALUES (25, 143) so the code seems to work

Comment: check updated code

Comment: still no luck. it just creates the User but nothing appears in the am_perm table

Answer (score 0):

I only have a semi answer for people who have a similar problem to me.  I was able to fix the above by using:

Mage::getModel('amperm/perm')->assignOneCustomer($userid, $customerId);

I have no idea ultimately though as to why I could manually write to the SQL database table, "am_perm" yet couldn't do it through an observer